# 99 Infiniti G20 not starting due to factory alarm issue

Tags: troubleshooting, alarm

I own a 1999 Infiniti G20 that has approx 150k miles. For the past week I have been dealing with an intermittent issue that seems to be related to the factory alarm system. When I shut the vehicle off the majority of the time it will not restart. The starter, alternator and the battery are all in working order and the the battery terminals are clean and nearly brand new. I can hear the fuel pump turn on when I turn the key to the "on" position as well. Usually if I leave the vehicle setting for a couple of hours it will start with no problem. However..I left it setting for a couple of hours and tried restarting it yesterday and had no luck. I then left it setting overnight (vehicle is locked and all windows secure as well as the trunk and hood). Tried to start it today and it wouldn't turn over. I have 2 keys to the vehicle (neither of them have a chip) and the keyfob. I have tried every suggestion for resetting the alarm system i.e. locking/unlocking with the fob as well as using the key in the driver side door and nothing seems to fix the issue. Unfortunately I lost my job and my only means of income currently has been freelance work using my vehicle and can't afford to take it to a service shop. I am a fairly skilled shadetree mechanic and am confident with some guidance I can correct the issue myself but unfortunately I haven't been able to find any info online that has been able to correct the issue. I did come across a post on a forum that mentioned grounding the wire that runs to the drivers side door lock to bypass the alarm system. The info wasn't very detailed though and I don't want to waste my time if it won't work. Does anyone know if this is a possible solution to my issue? If so, would you please provide me with detailed info on what I will need to do to accomplish this? Is it just as simple as tapping into the negative wire on the door lock  and grounding it out? Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Some formatting to make it readable would help, paragraphs etc